# Why don't I have to free heap objects when I pass them into a function?

Tags: c, malloc, free

The following program has no memory leaks. My question is, why does str1 and str2 not have to be passed into free(), even though I malloc'd both strings? Please see two commented locations in the code where I attempted to free str1 and str2, uncommenting that code resulted in an error saying I free'd a non-heap object. But from my understanding, str1 and str2 are objects created by malloc, hence are heap objects. I do not understand this contradiction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* StrCat(char* s1, const char* s2) {
    // Removing const from const char* s2
    //  made no difference on memory leak error message
    char *s, *tmp;
    s = tmp = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    strcpy(tmp, s1);
    tmp += strlen(s1);
    strcpy(tmp, s2);
    //free(str1); free(str2); Why not?
    printf("%d\n", s[strlen(s)] == '\0'); // Prints 1
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* str1 = malloc(4 * sizeof (char));
    str1 = "abc\n";
    char* str2 = malloc(6 * sizeof (char));
    str2 = "party\n";

    char* new = StrCat(str1, str2);
    //free(str1); free(str2); Why not?
    printf("%s\n", new);
    free(new); // Required
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may be lucky that the compiler spots that you throw away what `malloc()` returns in the `main()` function and optimizes away the call to `malloc()`, so you don't actually have any allocated memory to leak.  But in general, you need to free allocated memory.  Did you use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for memory leaks?

Comment: Note that if you do use `strcpy()` instead of pointer assignment, then the calls to `free()` are required — because the optimizer can't optimize away the calls to `malloc()` any more.  You should also verify that the calls are optimized away, maybe by reviewing the assembler output, or by compiling a file containing only `main()` and using `nm` to find the functions called (and if my hypothesis is correct, `malloc()` won't be called from `main()`).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to free heap objects, whether you pass them to a function or not.  Whatever is returned by `malloc()` must eventually be `free()`d, regardless of how you will use it.

Your problem is as follows:

The following line:

```
char* str1 = malloc(4 * sizeof (char));
```

allocates memory for 4 characters and stores a reference to it in `str1`.

The following line:

```
str1 = "abc\n";
```

forgets whatever memory `str1` was pointing to, (thus causing a memory leak,) and makes `str1` point to a new location, in your program's static data segment.  This is memory which was never allocated, and therefore may not be freed.

In order to solve your problem, instead of setting `str1` to point to `"abc\n"` you need to use `strcpy()` to copy `"abc\n"` to the allocated memory block which is pointed by `str1`.

Before doing that, do not forget to increment your `4` and your `6` by 1 each, because strings in C also contain a null-terminating byte, so you need to allocate space for `5` and `7` characters respectively.